# How to get all registered DbContext (or services) in ASP NET Core Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dbcontext

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 site, with several DbContext registered and some conditional connection strings.

For debug purposes, I want to list all `DbContext` registered and their connection string to ensure everything is well configured.

This is only a "test" functionality and is not used for any other use, so please no answer "you should not do that", "it is anti-pattern" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a way to do so.

In Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection>(services);
}
```

Then, display all services registered:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ServiceDescriptor sd in _SvcCollection.OrderBy(s=>s.ServiceType.Namespace).OrderBy(s=> s.ServiceType.Namespace.StartsWith("System")?0:s.ServiceType.Namespace.StartsWith("Microsoft.")?1:2))
{
    // sb.Append(sd.ServiceType.FullName) is not easy to read
    sb.Append(sd.ServiceType.NameSpace).Append(sd.ServiceType.Name);
    if(sd.ServiceType.IsGenericType)
        sb.Append("<")
          .Append(String.Join(",", sd.ServiceType.GenericTypeArguments.Select(a => a.Name)))
          .Append(">");

    sb.Append(": ").AppendLine(sd.LifeTime);
}
```

Display all DbContext registered with their connection string:

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ServiceDescriptor sd in _SvcCollection.Where(s => s.ServiceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbContext))))
{
    sb.Append(sd.ServiceType.Name).Append(": ").AppendLine(((DbContext)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(sd.ServiceType))?.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString);
}
```

Comment: What is _SvcCollection. Of what type is it? Where can I get one?

Comment: @Andrey `_SvcCollection` is just an injection of `IServiceCollection`

Answer (score 1):

If you use *top-level statements* (otherwise you could use different methods to find all the types, but the gist stays the same) in your `Program.cs` you can just do the following:

```
using var scope        = app.Services.CreateScope();
var       contextTypes = builder.Services
                                .Where(sd => sd.ServiceType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(DbContext)))
                                .Select(sd => sd.ServiceType);

foreach (var contextType in contextTypes) {
    var dbContext = (DbContext)scope.ServiceProvider
                                    .GetRequiredService(contextType);

    dbContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```